# How to solve this ODE: $\ddot{y}+\frac{1}{2f(y)}\frac{df(y)}{dy}(\dot{y})^2=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Initial conditions are $y(0)=A,\dot{y}(0)=B$, and $f(\cdot)>0$ is a given function.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Multiply everything by $2f(y) \dot{y}$. Then you have
$$ f(y) \cdot 2 \dot{y} \ddot{y} + f'(y) \dot{y} \cdot \dot{y}^2 = 0 $$
The important thing to notice here is that
$$ \frac{d}{dt} (\dot{y}^2) = 2\dot{y} \ddot{y}, $$
and
$$ \frac{d}{dt} (f(y)) = f'(y) \dot{y}, $$
so what you have here is a total derivative,
$$ \frac{d}{dt}  \left( \dot{y}^2 f(y) \right) = 0 $$
Therefore, integrating once,
$$ \dot{y}^2 f(y) - B^2 f(A) = C, $$
and $C=0$ by the boundary conditions. You can only now say
$$ \dot{y} \sqrt{f(y)} = \pm B^2 f(A), $$
which you can't get any further with unless you know what $f$ is: you can just rewrite it as
$$ \int_A^y \sqrt{f(Y)} \, dY = \pm B^2 f(A) t, $$
by integrating from $0$ to $t$ and substituting on the left.

Comment: My dear Chappers:  when I multiply  $\ddot{y}+\frac{1}{2f(y)}\frac{df(y)}{dy}(\dot{y})^2=0$ by $2f(y) \dot y$ I get $2f(y) \dot y \ddot y + \dfrac{df(y)}{dy} (\dot y)^3 = 0$, which differs from your result.  Any thoughts on the matter?  Cheers!

Comment: OK, it looks like your substituting in for $\ddot y$.  Right?  Checking . . . please wait . . .

Comment: @RobertLewis Ah, yes, made a typo there. I've fixed that bit.

Answer (score 1):

***Please Note:***  I think we've really got to hand to Chappers on this one; his solution method is most excellent, dealing with it does with the potentially problematic case $\dot y = 0$ without resorting to extended "exception handling" as might be required in the (admittedly incomplete) solution I've posted below.  Hopefully, I can return to this answer in short order and iron out some of the wrinkles, but before I rush off to work I thought I'd put forward a different technique for arriving at the solution.  ***Caveat emptor!!!***  The attentive reader may observe there are issues with signs I haven't fully addressed (yet).  But hopefully a different view of things will yield some, if imperfect, insight.  ***End of Note.***

Given the equation

$\ddot{y}+\dfrac{1}{2f(y)}\dfrac{df(y)}{dy}(\dot{y})^2=0, \tag{1}$

we can, assuming for the moment that $\dot y \ne 0$, divide by $\dot y$ to obtain

$\dfrac{\ddot y}{\dot y} + \dfrac{1}{2f(y)} \dfrac{df(y)}{dy} \dot y = 0; \tag{2}$

we observe that

$\dfrac{d \ln \dot y}{dt} = \dfrac{\ddot y}{\dot y} \tag{3}$

and that

$\dfrac{d \ln f(y)}{dt} = \dfrac{1}{f(y)} \dfrac{df(y)}{dy} \dot y; \tag{4}$

we thus find

$\dfrac{d \ln \dot y}{dt} + \dfrac{1}{2}\dfrac{d \ln f(y)}{dt} = 0, \tag{5}$

or

$\dfrac{d( \ln \dot y + \frac{1}{2} \ln f(y))}{dt} = 0; \tag{6}$

it follows from (6) that

$\ln \dot y + \frac{1}{2} \ln f(y) = C, \;\; \text{ a constant}; \tag{7}$

re-arranging

$\ln (\dot y (f(y))^{1/2}) = C, \tag{8}$

or

$\dot y (f(y))^{1/2} = e^C > 0. \tag{9}$

With

$y(0) = A, \dot y(0) = B \tag{10}$

we see *via* (8) that

$C = \ln (B (f(A))^{1/2}), \tag{11}$

whence

$e^C = B(f(A))^{1/2}, \tag{12}$

so that (9) becomes

$\dot y (f(y))^{1/2} = B(f(A))^{1/2}. \tag{13}$

Integrating with respect to $t$, (13) yields

$\int_A^y (f(s))^{1/2}ds = B(f(A))^{1/2}t, \tag{14}$

the result reached by Chappers *via* a different path.

Answer (score 0):

$\textbf{hint}$
$$
\ddot{y} = \frac{1}{2}\dfrac{d}{dy}\dot{y}^2
$$
And
$$
\dfrac{d}{dy}\ln f(y) = \frac{1}{f(y)}\frac{df(y)}{dy}
$$